# Selecting a number of related records into a result row

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I am currently writing an export function for an MS-Access database and i am not quite sure how to write a query that gives me the results that i want.
What i am trying to do is the following:

Let's say i have a table `Error` and there is a many-to-many relationship to the table `Cause`, modeled by the table `ErrorCause`. Currently i have a query similar to this (simplified, the original also goes one relationship further):

```
select Error.ID, Cause.ID
from ((Error inner join ErrorCauses on Error.ID = ErrorCauses.Error)
      left join Cause on ErrorCauses.Cause = Cause.ID)
```

I get something like this:

```
 Error | Cause
 -------------
 12345 | 12    
 12345 | 23    
 67890 | 23    
 67890 | 34
```

But i need to select the IDs of the first, say, 3 Causes for each error (even if those are empty), so that it looks like this:

```
 Error | Cause1 | Cause2 | Cause3
 --------------------------------
 12345 | 12     | 23     |       
 67890 | 23     | 34     |
```

Is there any way to do this in a single query?
Like selecting the Top 3 and then flattening this into the resulting row?
Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: cross tab query? http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-HA010229577.aspx

Comment: Take a look at SQL Server Pivot command.

Comment: @asantaballa this is not sql server

Comment: Ah, sorry. Saw MS and SQL and my mind dropped the ball. Please ignore.

Comment: What are you doing with the query afterwards?

Comment: @Linger I need to export it to CSV.

Comment: If you are going to export to csv then you can use a cross tab query and then iterate through the records.  Check to see if the field exist and if it does then add to csv file else move onto next field.

Comment: @Botz3000 I am working on an answer to this but I want to tweak your original query a bit. Is there a specific requirement in your problem to do a left join to the `Cause` table? To me it makes more sense to do an inner join because if a cause is in the `ErrorCauses` table it should also be in the `Cause` table. In fact you are probably enforcing this with a foreign key reference (or you should).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is for a specific number of causes--3. This makes it possible and manageable to get three different causes on the same row by doing a three-way join on the same subquery.

First, let's define your error-and-cause query as a straight-up Access query (a QueryDef object, if you want to be technical).

## `qryErrorCauseInfo`:

```
select
  Error.ID as ErrorID
, Cause.ID as CauseID
from (Error
inner join ErrorCauses
on Error.ID = ErrorCauses.Error)
left outer join Cause
on ErrorCauses.Cause = Cause.ID
```

By the way, I feel that the above left join should really be an inner join, for the reason I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052140/selecting-a-number-of-related-records-into-a-result-row#comment28174472_19052140).

Next, let's do a three-way join to get possible combinations of causes in rows:

## `qryTotalCause`:

```
select distinct
  *
, iif(Cause1 is null, 0, 1)
+ iif(Cause2 is null, 0, 1)
+ iif(Cause3 is null, 0, 1) as TotalCause
from (
  select
    eci1.ErrorID
  , eci1.CauseID as Cause1
  , iif(eci2.CauseID = Cause1, null, eci2.CauseID) as Cause2
  , iif(
      eci3.CauseID = Cause1 or eci3.CauseID = Cause2
    , null
    , eci3.CauseID
    ) as Cause3
  from (qryErrorCauseInfo as eci1
  left outer join qryErrorCauseInfo as eci2
  on eci1.ErrorID = eci2.ErrorID)
  left outer join qryErrorCauseInfo as eci3
  on eci2.ErrorID = eci3.ErrorID
) as sq
where (
  Cause1 < Cause2
  and Cause2 < Cause3
) or (
  Cause1 < Cause2
  and Cause3 is null
) or (
  Cause2 is null
  and Cause3 is null
) or (
  Cause1 is null
  and Cause2 is null
  and Cause3 is null
)
```

Finally, we need a correlated subquery to select, for each error, the one row with the highest number of causes (the rest of the rows are simply different permutations of the same causes):

```
select
  ErrorID
, Cause1
, Cause2
, Cause3
from qryTotalCause as tc1
where tc1.TotalCause = (
  select max(tc2.TotalCause)
  from qryTotalCause as tc2
  where tc1.ErrorID = tc2.ErrorID
)
```

Simple! (Not :-)

Comment: Wow, that's a bit more complex than i thought. I'll try this on monday and let you know how it works. :)

Comment: Yeah, a three-way join using the same table thrice creates a lot of superfluous result rows that we need to get rid of. That's where most of the complexity comes in. But having tested the whole thing just now, I am confident it works  May be a little slow though.

Comment: After some tweaking this really works :) I still have to figure out how to also get the 5 solutions for each cause, but this is a good starting point for me. Thanks!